# How to check if my Postgres is Enterprise or Community edition?

Tags: postgresql

When I select for version I get:

```
postgres=# SELECT version();
                                                 version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

But it doesn't says anything about  Enterprise/Community.

Comment: An "Enterprise Edition" has to be bought (there are several vendors) and I think in that case the version will display something else e.g. EnterpriseDB instead of PostgreSQL (but that is just a guess). Your version is the "usual" Postgres OpenSource version

Answer (score 0):

There are no "enterprise editions" or "community editions" of PostgreSQL. There is only a single edition of PostgreSQL, and that's what you are running.

Since PostgreSQL has a liberal license, it is easy to fork it, and there are many commercial forks out there. Some of them may call themselves "enterprise edition", "Postgres Plus" or similarly. You should be able to distinguish them by the `version()` output: If it doesn't say "PostgreSQL", it's not regular PostgreSQL.